# Problem assigning a new column in pandas when extracting values from different columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm having problem creating new column with average percantage of discount for a product category. My dataframe consists of rows with orders. Each order has its id, item name, category of a product, month of purchase, its retail and discounted price, I've also added discount in percentage column. I want to add a new column which would consist of an average discount per **category**. To put it in simple terms I want to know how much on average the products in **Furniture** were discounted. I then want to plot the top 3 categories with their discounts over time to see if there's seasonality (I was thinking of a bar plot).

That's example data

```
data = {'level_0':  ['Furniture', 'Jewllery','Watches', 'Footwear', 'Furniture', 'Watches'],
        'Discount_in_%': ['0.6', '.2', '0.3', '0.8', '0.7', '0.1']}

data = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['level_0','Discount_in_%'])
data
```

My problem is generating the column with the mean discount per category.
I was trying using `groupby()` but I get a column sull of NaNs

```
df['discount_in_%'] = 1 - df['discounted_price']/df['retail_price']


df['mean_discount_cat'] = df.groupby('level_0')['discount_in_%'].sum()/len(df)
df['mean_discount_cat']

#level_0 is the main category column

0       NaN
1       NaN
2       NaN
3       NaN
4       NaN
         ..
19995   NaN
19996   NaN
19997   NaN
19998   NaN
19999   NaN
```

I tried summing it up and then dividing it per length as when I used `mean()` I also got NaNs.
Can you please direct me how to fix this? Also I'm not sure how to then plot the mean discount just per top 3 categories, but that might be another issue.

I'd really appreciate your help.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems here.

1. Initializing the dataframe.  What you have isn't quite right.  It mixes two different ways of initializing. If you name the columns in the data, you do not pass the columns parameters into the initialization.  See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/different-ways-to-create-pandas-dataframe/

> ```
> data = {'level_0':  ['Furniture', 'Jewllery','Watches', 'Footwear', 'Furniture', 'Watches'],
>     'discount_in_%': [0.6, .2, 0.3, 0.8, 0.7, 0.1]}
>
> df = pd.DataFrame (data)
> ```

Now you have a proper dataframe.

2. group by is not quite right.  groupby function returns a special object that needs an aggregation function (not a column address) to produce results:

> ```
> print(df.groupby('level_0').sum())
> ```

3. dividing your results by len(df) doesn't make a lot of sense.  If you have 1 item in a category that has a 5% discount, what would dividing it by 100 items in the whole dataframe accomplish?  I am guessing you are looking for

> print(df.groupby('level_0').mean())

Comment: Thank you! My problem is that `df.groupby('level_0').mean()` doesn't sort values in descending orders, so I don't know which categories where discounted the most. Moreover, I need to find one mean per each category, not per item. That is something I have no idea how to accomplish. 
When I used `df.groupby('level_0').agg('mean')` I still get only NaNs throughout the whole column.

Comment: group_by().mean() will do exactly what you are asking for - mean per category.

It's equivalent to saying SELECT category, avg(col) FROM tbl GROUP BY category in SQL.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html - you can sort the result after you generated it.

Comment: You'll need to post working (albeit incorrectly) code for us to make sense of what's not working the way you like. Code as posted doesn't quite work.

Comment: But will I get the mean of all the values in the same category? Note that one category repeats in multiple rows and I need one mean for each of them.

Comment: This is what group_by does.  It groups by category column. So all rows that have the same value in that column will be grouped together.